# Client Script [Product Form] - Mode View

Tags: suitescript2.0

I wanted to display a message on the screen when a field the user is filling in is already registered in another product.
can anybody help me? Below the code:

Comment: Could you add your code? I am not sure if I understand the issue you are having but a client script cannot be triggered in VIEW mode of a record. You do not want your script to be triggered when you are editing the product? is that your issue? There are two different modes, CREATE and EDIT. You may only want to run your script in CREATE mode, you can use this function nlapiGetRecordId(); if it returns a value you are editing the product and you do not need to trigger the alert, if not you are creating the product and you should trigger the alert.

Comment: I used the saveRecord method. It is running for product creation and copying.
Now the problem is that in editing the saveRecord method is also validating. How to block validation in editing?

Comment: Below the code. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the following code in your saveRecord event:

```
if(!currentReocord.id){
  //put here all your logic for your validation
}
```

The above line will help you to determine if the user is creating the record.

Comment: It worked! But if when editing the item there is a change in the 'upccode' field. What do I do?
Can I use the fieldChanged event?

Comment: Add this snippet to the code:
if(currentRecord.id){
  if(ean_existe){
    return true;
  }
}

Comment: That is up to you. It seems you should use the fieldChange event and the line I suggested have to work as well. Please mark as accepted my solution since it solved your original question :)

Comment: Excuse me! I checked.

Now I need only to adjust this: if in the edition of the item there is a change in the EAN field ('upccode') and the value is the same for another registered item.
How do I display the alert? Is this in the saveRecord event or in the fieldChangeg event? Below the adjusted code.
Thanks for the help ...

Comment: You can do it in both but I would prefer to use a fieldChange to see the alert in real time. (also in both, when creating and editing)

Comment: It worked in the saveRecord event.
I'm updating the code here, if this topic is useful for someone.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of my friend Emerson Minero I am posting the code with the solution. I hope it can be useful to friends here. Thank you!

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @author Adriano Barbosa
 * @since 2019.2
 */
define(['N/log', 'N/record', 'N/search', 'N/ui/dialog'], function(log, record, search, dialog) {
    function pageInit(context) {
        if ( context.mode === 'copy' || context.mode === 'create' ) {
            var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
        }
    }

    function saveRecord(context) {
        var ean, item_id, ean_existe, codigo_item_sap;
        var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;

        item_id = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'itemid' });
        ean = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'upccode' });
        // Valida o EAN na cópia/criação do item
        if (!ean) {
            dialog.alert({ title: 'Alerta: EAN não informado', message: 'Informe o EAN para prosseguir cadastro.' });
            log.debug({ title: '[Cópia/Criação do Item] ' + 'Alerta: EAN não informado', details: 'Informe o EAN para prosseguir cadastro.' });
            return false; 
        } else {
            search.create({ type: "item",
                filters: [
                    [ "upccode", "is", ean ]
                ],
                columns: [
                    search.createColumn({ name: "internalid", label: "ID interna" }),
                    search.createColumn({ name: "upccode", label: "Código UPC" })
                ]
            }).run().each(function (result) {
                item_id = result.id;
                ean_existe = result.getValue({ name: 'upccode' });
                codigo_item_sap = record.load({ type: 'inventoryitem', id: item_id, isDynamic: true })
                                        .getValue({ fieldId: 'itemid' });
                return false;
            });
        }
        // Valida o EAN na edição do Item
        if (currentRecord.id) {
            ean = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'upccode' });
            if (!ean) {
                dialog.alert({ title: 'Alerta: EAN não informado', message: 'Informe o EAN para prosseguir cadastro.' });
                log.debug({ title: '[Edição do Item] ' + 'Alerta: EAN não informado', details: 'Informe o EAN para prosseguir cadastro.' }); 
                return false;
            } else {
                search.create({ type: "item",
                    filters: [
                        [ "upccode", "is", ean ]
                    ],
                    columns: [
                        search.createColumn({ name: "internalid", label: "ID interna" }),
                        search.createColumn({ name: "upccode", label: "Código UPC" })
                    ]
                }).run().each(function (result) {
                    item_id = result.id;
                    ean_existe = result.getValue({ name: 'upccode' });
                    codigo_item_sap = record.load({ type: 'inventoryitem', id: item_id, isDynamic: true })
                                            .getValue({ fieldId: 'itemid' });
                    return false;
                });
            }
            // [Edição do Item] - Se encontrado o EAN na base, impede o salvamento.
            if ((item_id != currentRecord.id) && codigo_item_sap) {
                dialog.alert({ title: 'Alerta: EAN ' + ean_existe + ' já cadastrado!', 
                    message: 'O item: ' + '"' + codigo_item_sap + '"' + ' já possui este mesmo EAN' + '. Informe outro EAN para prosseguir cadastro.' 
                });
                log.debug({ title: '[Edição do Item] ' + 'Alerta: EAN ' + ean_existe + ' já cadastrado!', 
                    details: 'Verifique o código do item: ' + '"' + codigo_item_sap + '".' 
                });
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (ean_existe) { // [Cópia/Criação do Item] - Se encontrado o EAN na base, impede o salvamento.
            dialog.alert({ title: 'Alerta: EAN ' + ean_existe + ' já cadastrado!', 
                message: 'O item: ' + '"' + codigo_item_sap + '"' + ' já possui este mesmo EAN' + '. Informe outro EAN para prosseguir cadastro.' 
            });
            log.debug({ title: '[Cópia/Criação do Item] ' + 'Alerta: EAN ' + ean_existe + ' já cadastrado!', 
                details: 'Verifique o código do item: ' + '"' + codigo_item_sap + '".' 
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            log.debug({ title: 'Item cadastrado!', 
                details: '"Código Item SAP:" ' + currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'itemid' }) + ', "EAN:" ' + currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'upccode' }) 
            });
            return true;
        }
    }  
    return { pageInit: pageInit, saveRecord: saveRecord }
});
```